# Conditional if statement not working php versions

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Using Boostrap and PHP I want my code to display both fields using (`class="col-sm-6"`) if field C is present. If not then only display field B only using (`class="col-sm-12"`). It ain't working. Please help ?

`PHP 5.4`...I get no error but if statement does not work the way I want when using `PHP 5.3`...I Get a (`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$gem_gemstone_para_c in`) error

Here is my code.

```
<?php if (is_null($row->gem_gemstone_para_c)){ ?>
 <div class="post row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <img src="<?php echo $GemstonesImagesDir;?>/<?php echo $row->gem_gemstone_picture_b; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <img src="<?php echo $GemstonesImagesDir;?>/<?php echo $row->gem_gemstone_picture_c; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="post row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <img src="<?php echo $GemstonesImagesDir;?>/<?php echo $row->gem_gemstone_picture_b; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it appears `gem_gemstone_para_c` is not a member of `$row`. Could you `var_dump($row);`?

Comment: Check before if property exists: if( !isset($row->gem_gemstone_para_c) or is_null($row->gem_gemstone_para_c) )

Comment: Guys, thank you but i managed by adding a new field and checking the if statement on that. For some or other reason the If Statement and what i had just would not work. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to check if the property is set and is not null. There is a [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) in PHP which exactly does that. You code will look something like this.

```
<?php if (!isset($row->gem_gemstone_para_c)){ ?>
 <div class="post row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <img src="<?php echo $GemstonesImagesDir;?>/<?php echo $row->gem_gemstone_picture_b; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <img src="<?php echo $GemstonesImagesDir;?>/<?php echo $row->gem_gemstone_picture_c; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="post row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <img src="<?php echo $GemstonesImagesDir;?>/<?php echo $row->gem_gemstone_picture_b; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```